# Want to do some work before app being terminated in swift

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

1 -I want to do some work before application go to terminate state in swift.How to do it ? let take an example - i want to delete data from coredata.

2- If the coredata has a large amount of data. which will take more time to delete. then how to do it ? Is there any estimated time to go to terminate state in swift.

Comment: Which platform are you talking about?

Comment: ios using swift

Answer (score 1):

The last event you are *guaranteed* of receiving before app termination is `applicationDidEnterBackground(_:)`. If you might need extra time to complete a lengthy task, use `beginBackgroundTask(expirationHandler:)`.

Comment: All the information you need is in the docs for UIApplication and UIApplicationDelegate.

Answer (score 0):

If your application has the need to start with a clean slate, the addition of *destroyPersistentStoreAtURL(_:withType:options:)* resolves this problem.
Example:

```
do {
    try persistentStoreCoordinator.destroyPersistentStoreAtURL(persistentStoreURL, withType: NSSQLiteStoreType, options: nil)
} catch { }
```

Try this on your dataStoreCoordinator on AppDelegate.